# C++ string dynamic 2D array cause memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-leaks

When I use a string type dynamic 2D array, there is memory leak after deleting the array.
Please view the following code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;        

#define NEW2D(H, W, TYPE) (TYPE **)new2d(H, W, sizeof(TYPE))

void* new2d(int h, int w, int size)
{
    register int i;
    void **p;

    p = (void**)new char[h*sizeof(void*) + h*w*size];
    for(i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        p[i] = ((char *)(p + h)) + i*w*size;
    }

    return p;
}
```

If I use the following code:

```
    string** pstr = NEW2D(2, 4, string);
    memset(pstr[0], 0, sizeof(string)*2*4);

    delete [] pstr;

There is no memory leak; however, if I use the following code:
    string** pstr = NEW2D(2, 4, string);
    memset(pstr[0], 0, sizeof(string)*2*4);

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            pstr[j][i] = "test";

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            pstr[j][i].clear();

    delete [] pstr;
```

The memory leak is happened, even if I have called pstr[j][i].clear().

What should I do to avoid memory leak after having

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        pstr[j][i] = "test";
```

in my code?

Comment: How do you know that there is a memory leak? Also try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Allocating `std::string` without initializing (via constructor) will not work.

Comment: If you want a function to allocate and initialise a 2D array, then make it a template function so that it works with any type. Your code is irretrievably bugged because it creates `std::string` objects without calling any `std::string` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code because it treats non-trivial types like `std::string` as if they were trivial. Probably you could create something using *placement new* that was legal C++ and worked in a similar way to the code you've written

But here's an simple alternative that (hopefully) works

```
template <typename T>
T** new2d(int h, int w)
{
    T** p = new T*[h];
    T* q = new T[h*w];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        p[i] = q + i*w;
    return p;
}
```

And to delete

```
template <typename T>
void free2d(T** p, int h)
{
    if (h > 0)
        delete[] p[0];
    delete[] p;
}
```

Untested code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have tried the following code:
 string** pstr = NEW2D(2, 4, string);
 memset(pstr[0], 0, sizeof(string)*2*4);

 for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   pstr[j][i] = "test";

 for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  delete [] pstr[j];

 delete [] pstr;

The program will crash when run at delete [] pstr[j] as 0XC0000005 error.

Comment: @WilliamSung The program crashes for the same reason **you are not constructing your strings with a string constructor**. **Any** attempt to use strings like that is bugged. Also any attempt to use `memset` on a string is bugged. You cannot treat strings as if they are trivial types. `std::string` is not like `int` or `double`. You must use proper constructors proper allocation and string methods only in string code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John. I have tried the following code, it works well:

```
int i;
int data_height = 2, data_width = 4;
string **data;
data = new string*[data_height];
for(i = 0; i < data_height; i++)
    data[i] = new string[data_width];

for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        data[j][i] = "test";

for(i = 0; i < data_height; i++)
    delete [] data[i];
delete [] data;
```

Comment: You can use `std::vector` of vectors to model 2D arrays in a much more comfortable and safer way. And if your dimensions are compile time constants, you can use `std::array` instead and avoid dynamic allocations/deallocations.